# Does app.js in ExpressJS import all re-require files again each page load?

Tags: node.js, express

In ExpressJS, the main app.js file as far as I am aware is loaded first and imports all code it needs such as require('myclass.js') lines, including routes etc.

My question is, does every time a user request a page from Express (home page, login page etc), does Express then run all the code in app.js AGAIN? Requiring all files etc. Seems like a huge amount of overhead?

I've never found a clear answer to this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, does every time a user request a page from Express (home page, login page etc), does Express then run all the code in app.js AGAIN? Requiring all files etc. Seems like a huge amount of overhead?

No.  The top level code in `app.js` is run once at server startup time.  That code loads module dependencies, creates the Express `app` object and then registers route handlers on it and then starts the http server.

A route handler that matches an incoming http request will be called each time that matching incoming request arrives, but only that request handler and any appropriate middleware will be called.  The Express app and all the route handlers are initialized only once.

Your code in node.js differs from some other environments in that your code and all its routes are initialized once at server startup time and that server object then stays running, ready to field every incoming request and divert it to the appropriate request handlers.  Likewise any module state you set in node.js is available to all future requests too.

So, when a user hits the `/login` URL, only the express request handler for that page (and any configured middleware) is run.  Other routes are just sitting there waiting for an incoming request that matches their route configuration.